# Arbitrary Bytes in WebAssembly Data Section

Tags: webassembly

Every example I've seen in WebAssembly for a data section uses a string, i.e.

```
(data (i32.const 16) "Hello World")
```

How can I use these sections with binary data? How could I do something equivalent to...

```
(data (i32.const 16) 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03)
```

Do I have to use `i32.store`?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up solving this issue by escaping the bytes with a backslash inside of a string. I don't know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
(data (i32.const 16) "\00\01\02\03")
```

Answer (score 3):

The WebAssembly specification has a section which [details the WAT text format](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/index.html).

The data section [defines data for a given memory index and offset by a string](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/modules.html#data-segments). The format of this string is specified [elsewhere in the specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/values.html#text-string). It is a UTF8 encoding, with a small number of escape sequences `∖hh` that encode things like tabs, linefeeds, and `\u` which encodes bytes in hex.

This might not look terribly compact, however, when compiled to wasm, it is stored as a sequence of bytes.